# values incorrectly sorted in SQLite3 query order by

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am making a very simple query on my Sqlite database and I'm asking to sort the recipes by the calories. I need the highest value to be on the bottom therefore I'm not saying DESC on my query.

This is the statement:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from recipes order by calories;
```

This is what the top part of the output looks like:

```
id|name|is_vegetarian|is_vegan|is_gluten_free|calories|fats|proteins|carbs|source
83|Vegan Cobb Salad Recipes|N/A|N/A|N/A| 1003| 38| 104| 72|https://yumveganlunchideas.com/vegan-cobb-salad-recipe/
67|Meal Prep Caprese Chicken Quinoa Bowls|N/A|N/A|N/A| 1108| 55| 55| 97|https://wholefully.com/chicken-quinoa-bowl-meal-prep/
73|Spicy Thai Chicken & Brown Rice Bowls|N/A|N/A|N/A| 1305| 96.4| 39.8| 87.4|https://www.thekitchn.com/recipe-spicy-thai-chicken-and-brown-rice-bowls-259055
70|Chicken Burrito Bowls Meal Prep|N/A|N/A|N/A| 520| 13| 37| 64|https://allnutritious.com/chicken-burrito-bowls/
65|Sheet Pan Cashew Chicken|N/A|N/A|N/A| 579| 40| 33| 25|https://allnutritious.com/sheet-pan-cashew-chicken/
62|Sheet Pan Chicken & Cauliflower|N/A|N/A|N/A| 583| 39| 47| 14|https://allnutritious.com/sheet-pan-chicken-cauliflower/
75|Avocado Tuna Salad|N/A|N/A|N/A| 602| 28| 50.9| 44.8|https://unboundwellness.com/avocado-tuna-salad/
76|Chicken Burrito Bowl|N/A|N/A|N/A| 606| 23| 36| 65|https://feelgoodfoodie.net/recipe/chicken-burrito-bowl-cilantro-lime-rice/
79|Salmon Taco Bowls|N/A|N/A|N/A| 616| 23.1| 35.4| 68.2|https://www.ambitiouskitchen.com/salmon-taco-bowls/
77|Easy Teriyaki Chicken Meal Prep|N/A|N/A|N/A| 626| 6| 57| 80|https://thefoodcafe.com/easy-teriyaki-chicken-meal-prep/
74|Baked Herb Chicken Breasts with Couscous Meal Prep|N/A|N/A|N/A| 633| 17| 61| 56|https://allnutritious.com/herb-chicken-couscous-meal-prep/
81|Avocado Bacon Chicken Salad|N/A|N/A|N/A| 640| 38| 57| 9|https://www.savorytooth.com/keto-chicken-salad/
```

This is what the bottom part of the output looks like:

```
44|Perfect Roast Chicken with Lemon Herb Pan Sauce|0|0|1|576|28|66|3|https://themodernproper.com/perfect-roast-chicken-with-lemon-herb-pan-sauce
29|Coconut Curry Ramen|1|0|0|584|40|17|43|https://themodernproper.com/coconut-curry-ramen
13|Old Bay Shrimp and Sausage Sheet Pan Dinner|0|0|1|596|51|24|13|https://themodernproper.com/old-bay-shrimp-and-sausage-sheet-pan-dinner
17|Pork Chops with Mushroom Cream Sauce|0|0|1|622|44|31|15|https://themodernproper.com/pork-chops-with-mushroom-cream-sauce
1|Broccoli Pesto Pasta|1|0|0|623|43|16|47|https://themodernproper.com/broccoli-pesto-pasta
56|Huevos Rancheros|1|0|1|625|5|36|108|https://themodernproper.com/huevos-rancheros
42|Skillet Roasted Chicken with Cabbage|0|0|1|629|24|89|7|https://themodernproper.com/skillet-roasted-chicken-with-cabbage
8|Five Spice Chicken Sheet Pan Dinner|0|0|1|648|49|39|14|https://themodernproper.com/five-spice-chicken-sheet-pan-dinner
40|Easy Harissa Chicken|0|0|1|660|36|68|14|https://themodernproper.com/easy-harissa-chicken
38|Easy Bolognese|0|0|1|668|20|54|63|https://themodernproper.com/easy-bolognese
25|Taco Soup|0|0|1|670|7|54|100|https://themodernproper.com/taco-soup
19|Sheet Pan Italian Sausage Heros with Honey Mustard|0|0|0|733|44|33|56|https://themodernproper.com/sheet-pan-italian-sausage-heros-with-honey-mustard
```

The bottom part seems to be working since it goes form 576 to 670, I just don't understand why the top part starts off with 1003-1108-1305-520-579

I believe the problem is that when I created the table I didn't specify that calories was going to be used for Integer values, but then again the bottom part is being correctly sorted (not really since it's sorting from smaller to greatest but it's following a specific pattern)

This is what the SCHEMA looks like

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name, is_vegetarian, is_vegan, is_gluten_free, calories, fats, proteins, carbs, source);
```

Thank you for taking the time to read. Please let me know what you guys think.

Comment: Read about [column affinity](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity). Specifically, pay close attention to the rules for BLOBs and in the examples related to them.

Comment: so the problem was indeed in the creation of the table. I guess the fact that the bottom part was being sorted is just a coincidence then, right? Thank you for the source btw